# Vectorize call to function of two vectors (treat matrix as array of vector)

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, vectorization

I wish to compute the cumulative cosine distance between sets of vectors.
The natural representation of a set of vectors is a matrix...but how do I vectorize the following?

```
function d = cosdist(P1,P2)
    ds = zeros(size(P1,2),1);
    for k=1:size(P1,2)
      %#used transpose() to avoid SO formatting on '
        ds(k)=transpose(P1(:,k))*P2(:,k)/(norm(P1(:,k))*norm(P2(:,k)));
    end
    d = prod(ds);
end
```

I can of course write

```
fz = @(v1,v2) transpose(v1)*v2/(norm(v1)*norm(v2));
ds = cellfun(fz,P1,P2);
```

...so long as I recast my matrices as cell arrays of vectors.  Is there a better / entirely numeric way?
Also, will cellfun, arrayfun, etc. take advantage of vector instructions and/or multithreading?

**Note** probably superfluous in present company but for column vectors `v1'*v2 == dot(v1,v2)` and is significantly faster in Matlab.

Comment: The `cellfun()` version is actually slower, even without preallocation.

Comment: Interestingly, `p'*q` is the fastest dot product for vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `P1` and `P2` are of the same size, you can do element-wise operations here. `v1'*v` equals `sum(v1.*v2)`, by the way.

```
d = prod(sum(P1.*P2,1)./sqrt(sum(P1.^2,1) .* sum(P2.^2,1)));
```

Comment: Should have seen that...ah, so.  It's about 20 times faster, too.

Comment: you should add a missing closing parenthesis at the end, and change the multiplication sign to an element-wise operation `.*`

Comment: @Amro: Thanks. That's what I get for not copy-pasting - and I even counted parentheses!

Answer (score 3):

[@Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885524/vectorize-call-to-function-of-two-vectors-treat-matrix-as-array-of-vector/4886237#4886237) had the right idea, but the normalizing denominator might be incorrect. Try this instead:

```
%# matrix of column vectors
P1 = rand(5,8);
P2 = rand(5,8);

d = prod( sum(P1.*P2,1) ./ sqrt(sum(P1.^2,1).*sum(P2.^2,1)) );
```

---

You can compare this against the results returned by [PDIST2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/pdist2.html) function:

```
%# PDIST2 returns one minus cosine distance between all pairs of vectors
d2 = prod( 1-diag(pdist2(P1',P2','cosine')) );
```

Comment: BTW: Congrats to a new gold badge :)

Comment: @Jonas: still not there yet but thanks.. looks like you'll be joining the club soon ;)

Comment: Vote counts are  updated during the night, so you'll have to wait a bit. See you there in a few weeks :)